# How to simulate this Corrective Maintenance versus Preventive Maintenance replacement problem in r?

Tags: r, excel, simulation

The Heavy Duty Company has just purchased a large machine for a new
production process.The machine is powered by a motor that occasionally breaks down and
requires a major overhaul. Therefore, a second standby motor is kept, and the
two motors are rotated in use.The breakdowns always occur on the fourth, fifth, or sixth day that the motor is in use. Fortunately, it takes fewer than three days to overhaul a motor, so areplacement is always ready.

```
#Cost of a Replacement Cycle that Begins with a Breakdown#
-Replace a Motor :$2,000
-Lost production during replacement: $5,000
-Overhaul a motor:$4,000
-Total:$11,000
```

#Preventive Maintenance Options#
Preventive maintenance would involve scheduling the motor to be removed
(and replaced) for an overhaul at a certain time, even if a breakdown has not
occurred. The goal is to provide maintenance early enough to prevent a breakdown.
Scheduling the overhaul enables removing and replacing the motor at a convenient time when the machine is not in use, so no production is lost.

```
#Cost of a Replacement Cycle that Begins without a Breakdown#
+Replace a motor on overtime:$3,000
+Lost production during replacement:$0
+Overhaul a motor before a breakdown:$3,000
+Total:$6,000
```

The Cost of a replacement cycle is $6,000. (Replacement always occurs without a
breakdown) and the Replacement cycle occurs every three days.

Here is the simulation done in excel:
[corrective maintenance image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI2FR.png)  [replace motor post 4 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oBIo.png)  [replace motor post 5 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A4Pr.png)

How can i replicate the same results using r code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It’s easier to help if you include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as dat <- data.frame(…) where … is your variable(s) and values or use dput(head(dataframe))

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, Peter. I'll make sure to keep these pointers in mind. There's no dataset used just the information that i provided. I wasn't sure how to show the simulation work done in excel so i included screenshots of the same